# Apache Pig fetch max from a data-set that has Groups

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, apache-pig

I have a data-set stored in **HDFS** in a file called **temp.txt** which is as follows :

```
US,Arizona,51.7
US,California,56.7
US,Bullhead City,51.1
India,Jaisalmer,42.4
Libya,Aziziya,57.8
Iran,Lut Desert,70.7
India,Banda,42.4
```

Now, I load this into Pig memory through the following command :

```
temp_input = LOAD '/WC/temp.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as 
(country:chararray,city:chararray,temp:double);
```

After this, I **GROUPED** all the data in **temp_input** as :

```
 group_country = GROUP temp_input BY country;
```

When I dump the data in **group_country**, following output is displayed on screen:

```
(US,{(US,Bullhead City,51.1),(US,California,56.7),(US,Arizona,51.7)})
(Iran,{(Iran,Lut Desert,70.7)})
(India,{(India,Banda,42.4),(India,Jaisalmer,42.4)})
(Libya,{(Libya,Aziziya,57.8)})
```

Once the data-set is grouped, I tried to fetch the country name and indivisual maximum temperatures for each each in **group_country** through the following query :

```
max_temp = foreach group_country generate group,max(temp);
```

This punches out an error which looks like :

```
017-06-21 13:20:34,708 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 
1070: Could not resolve max using imports: [, java.lang., 
org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
Details at logfile: /opt/ecosystems/pig-0.16.0/pig_1498026994684.log
```

What should be my next move to resolve this error and fetch the required result.
All help is appreciated.

Comment: `MAX` is valid, `max` is not.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While transforming relations pig use `describe relationname` this will help to know how to iterate. So in your case:

```
desribe group_country;
```

Should give you a output like:

```
group_country: {group: chararray,temp_input: {(country: chararray,city: chararray,temp: double)}}
```

Then the query :

```
max_temp = foreach group_country GENERATE group,MAX(temp_input.temp);
```

Output:

```
(US,56.7) (Iran,70.7) (India,42.4) (Libya,57.8)
```

**Updated as per comment:**

```
finaldata = foreach group_country {
    orderedset = order temp_input by temp DESC;
    maxtemps = limit orderedset 1;
    generate flatten(maxtemps);
}
```

Comment: @TKHNsweet! 
That was bang on target. I was hung up on this for a long time.
You sir area savior.

Comment: @TKHNwhat if i want to display the corresponding city?

Comment: Thanks a ton mate. I have learnt so much today. Awesome methodology I must say. @TKHN